# Validation Not Working Propely On ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, validation

if we use validator with in ngRepeat then its Not working properly it
Its perform validation at last input..... What is the solution of it??

Module : https://github.com/huei90/angular-validation

See the example :-

http://plnkr.co/edit/1PwcjDOyXuQBUEA8N6J7?p=preview

```
  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <form name="demoform">
        <div class="input" ng-repeat="$i in list">
            <input 
              type="text" 
              ng-model="list[$index].name"
              name="field_{{$index}}" validator="required"  />
        </div>

       <button validation-submit="demoform" ng-click="submit()" >Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: This seems weird `ng-model="list[$index].name"` ... why not `ng-model="$i"`?

Comment: PS: You should avoid using $-prefixed variables. The $ dollar sign is reserved for native angular variables

Comment: I tried but yet not working ..... Please check it

http://embed.plnkr.co/nMaLPr/preview

Please make a example for me....

Comment: Your example in plunkr works for me - it shows message "it is required" when I enter value, just like it is defined in validation-rule.js. What exactly is not working?

Comment: PS: Why don't you use built-in validation? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms - section "Custom Validation"

Comment: if u click on submit before enter enter any data on any field u will see error message on last field not on all fields.... Validation perfome on last one not on all field try once ......

Comment: you use `ng-click="submit()"` but no `submit` method is defined on the controller